# Why do my time-related unit tests break every day at 4pm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, datetime

For a long time I've been having this issue that at a certain time of the day, a TON of my tests break. I have a lot of tests that are doing simple date comparisons and everything runs fine from midnight to like 4:00 in the afternoon. Any idea why this is happening? I've set my timezone in my environment file too.

It seems like some of my calls like 5.days.from_now.to_date are adding an extra day.

Edit

For instance, this test fails:

```
# Widget that creates items for how many days the trip is gone.
def test_should_create_correct_amount_of_days_for_trip
  w = DayWidget.create(:trip => trips(:hawaii))
  assert_equal w.days.size, 5
end

# Code in trip model that calculates amount of days
def number_of_days
  (self.return_date.to_date - self.depart_date.to_date).to_i + 1
end

# Test fixture yaml for Hawaii
hawaii:
  depart_date: <%= Time.now.tomorrow.to_s(:db) %>
  return_date: <%= 5.days.from_now.to_s(:db) %>
```

After 4:00 pm, the test above fails and says it created 6 days instead of 5. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably in the Pacific time zone, 8 hours behind UTC (which is why at 4:00p they start breaking, since that's when it hits midnight UTC).

Without seeing your test/comparison code, all I could say is to make sure you're comparing dates/times with the same location (UTC to UTC or localtime to localtime).

**Update:** Ok, it looks like `Time.now` returns a `Time` object, whereas using `XXX.days.from_now` returns an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object, resulting in different handling of timezones:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :009 > (Time.now+5.days).to_s(:db)
 => "2011-02-08 19:40:24" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :010 > 5.days.from_now.to_s(:db)
 => "2011-02-09 03:40:29"
```

My recommendation would be to either call `.utc` on your times in your fixtures like so:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :017 > 5.days.from_now.utc.to_s(:db)
 => "2011-02-09 03:42:39" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :018 > (Time.now+5.days).utc.to_s(:db)
 => "2011-02-09 03:42:39"
```

or to just switch to using `1.day.from_now` instead of `Time.now.tomorrow` to keep the types consistent.

Comment: Yeah everything seems to be getting compared correctly. I just edited my post to show an example. Thanks

Comment: See my updated answer... `Time.now` returns a completely different class type than `5.days.from_now`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! That definitely was the problem in my code. I had no idea different time objects were being returned. The problem now is that I have a bunch of time objects in my code base that I'm mixing and matching(Time.now and 1.day.ago). Should I just apply .utc to every time object for consistency or is that overkill?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Time.current`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#time-current) instead of `Time.now`.

`Time.current` returns `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` just like `#ago` and `#from_now`, so you can safely compare dates returned by them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are truly dealing with just dates, be sure to set the hours, minutes and seconds to 0, otherwise you are at the mercy of the time of day you create the dates.

Comment: Set them to 0 in the database or in my comparisons?

Comment: Set them to zero when you create your Date objects.